# How to find element without use ID

Tags: javascript

I have DOM element in array

```
this.object = 
     <div>
     <span class="color">"color1</span> 
     <span class="text">text1</span>
     </div>

     <div>
     <span class="color">"color2</span> 
     <span class="text">text2</span>
     </div>

     <div>
     <span class="color">"color3</span> 
     <span class="text">text3/span>
     </div>

     <div>
     <span class="color">"color4</span> 
     <span class="text">text4</span>
     </div>
```

this DOM is exist in array of DOM ( this.object )

How I update only the first span or only the second span in the array, I can't use ID from technical issue of my program.

I tried to use
`this.element.children[i]` but then I didn't know how to find the first or second span

Comment: What is `this`? The `div` element?

Comment: sorry , this should be array of DOM element that have the structute <div><span></span><span></span></div>

Comment: Maybe a http://jsfiddle.net could help illustrating your issue if you don't get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery to avoid any cross browser issues. Assuming you have the div, use `div.find('span:eq(1)');`

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybu6n/)

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybu6n/1/) for multiple items.

Another [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybu6n/2/) showing the text being updated.

Comment: thanks, I update my question how is it possible to do it to array of DOM ?

Comment: @user1365697 See new example with multiple divs.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `this.element[i]` to access any element in the array, and then you can access the children of those elements:

```
this.element[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML = "paint one";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use jquery and then you can write it like this:

```
$('.color').html('updated text')
```

Comment: it is possible without jquery ?

Comment: also I have array of DOO the have same information, how i can find the relevant instance

Answer (score 1):

You could use [querySelectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector):

```
//find first element with class 'color' within a div
//returns an element Node
[yourdiv].querySelector('.color');
//find all elements with class 'color' within a document
//returns a nodeList
document.querySelectorAll('.color');
```

Or [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName):

```
//find first element with class 'color' within a div
//returns a nodeList with 1 or more elements
[yourdiv].getElementsByClassname('.color')[0];
//find all elements with class 'color' within a document
//returns a nodeList
document.getElementsByClassName('.color');
```

Comment: Though note that both options are not cross browser compatible.

Comment: *Not cross browser compatible* most of times signifies: IE has a problem with it. For these methods: `querySelector` is supported from IE>7. For `getElementsByClassName` there are shims, like http://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/source/browse/trunk/getElementsByClassName.js.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getElementsByClassName()`.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("color")[0];
```

But you have to remember two things: 1.) `getElementsByClassName()` is not fully cross-browser compatible. 2.) You have two know at what position your `color` element is. If you only using the class `color` once the example works perfectly.

Two solve issue 1.) you can use following workaround:

```
function getElementsByClassName(node, classname) {
    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp('(^| )'+classname+'( |$)');
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
        if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);
    return a;
}
```